# Loading from a JSON configuration file into an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm a Javascript novice, so for all I know I want the impossible.

I have a page that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//static.foo.com/x/js/file1.js"></script>
    <script src="//static.foo.com/x/js/file2.js"></script>
    ...
    <script src="//static.foo.com/x/js/file10.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have many included files at the same static location.  It's possible that the HTML file might be used in a different way by someone else where they include the files from a different static location, so I'd like to introduce a `config.json` file where this and other things can be specified, e.g.:

```
{
  "streamingApiLocation": "//stream.something.com/",
  "staticAssetLocation": "//static.foo.com/x/", 
  "authApiLocation": "//auth.something.com/"
}
```

Somehow this would be loaded into my page, and my script inclusions would be something like:

```
    <script src="config.staticAssetLocation + js/file1.js"></script>
    <script src="config.staticAssetLocation + js/file2.js"></script>
    ...
    <script src="config.staticAssetLocation + js/file10.js"></script>
```

...this of course is not proper syntax... But basically I'm looking for a way to have variable information in `script` tags in the header, based on information provided in a JSON file.

Is something like this even remotely possible?

Comment: not possible like that. `src` isn't javascript code. it's a URI. you could have another script GENERATE new `<script>` tags and insert them into the DOM

Comment: Take a look at a javascript framework, many of them have dependency management, and help you take care of basic tasks like this. I'd recommend angularJS as a good place to start

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/4434366) it may help.

Comment: You should just concatenate and minify your files, there are many libs available to do that for you, e.g. with gulp or grunt

Comment: Also keep in mind that you may run in to cross-domain restrictions given your example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222822/why-do-browser-apis-restrict-cross-domain-requests

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `<script>` tag dynamically.

```
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'helper.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
```

Ref: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Comment: This will not work as expected if the dynamically added script tag is hosted on a resource external to the source domain.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers how to make a script tag dynamically, but how would I load the configuration file into the page?