# origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policies error in codeigniter only due to the path in config page :- Not duplicate question

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am getting an error like:

```
origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This error occurs only when the design is integrated in codeigniter.

Please note who all added this question as duplicate.
my question is not a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) .
My solution is added as the comment.
Since, some geeks who think that, its a duplicate question, and reviewd it like so, I am not able to answer my own question. Once I get the privilage to add so, I will move the comment to answer.

Thankyou

Comment: What does this has to do with css?

Comment: In short, you must config your server to accept CORS requests. More information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: check if you have some request to i.e. `http://localhost/...` css or js file

Comment: @AVAVT, I think it's incorrect to say "you must config your server to *accept* CORS requests".  It's the opposite.  The server Raru is attempting to connect to needs to include CORS header(s) in it's *response*.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah you're right, I didn't notice that until now o_0

Comment: @AVAVT, another useful piece of information: The browser is what is restricting the connection.  If no CORS header is present in the Response, the browser won't connect (maybe not all browsers though).  However, since no CORS headers are present at all, you *would* be able to connect to that origin from another server, *unless* the HTTP Response specifically whitelists certain origins excluding yours / blacklists your origin. The browsers are doing this to prevent potentially malicious documents. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222822/why-do-browser-apis-restrict-cross-domain-requests

Comment: I got the answer. In application configuration I had change like this.


$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/rvci/';

and this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add headers in Your `requested` page:

```
  // headers
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Methods, Content-Type");
```

**EDIT**

in `codeigniter`:

```
$this->output
        ->set_content_type("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
        ->set_content_type("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST")
        ->set_content_type("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Methods, Content-Type")
```

Comment: I am really sorry... It didn't make any changes.

Comment: @Raru, these headers need to be included in the HTTP Response of the server your trying to connect to.  If you don't have control of the that server, then you won't be able to connect via the browser.  You will, however, be able to connect from another server.  The browser is what is restricting you here.